# prove that if a nonempty subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is both open and closed, then $S=\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have to prove that if a nonempty subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is both open and closed, then $S=\mathbb{R}^n$

Does anyone have an idea I am new to this stuff.

Comment: Okay I will take a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: Hint. Does it help to think of this as the impossibility of covering the space by two disjoint proper open subsets? Or closed subset?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\phi\ne A\subset \mathbb R^n$ and  $A$ is open and closed.

Take any $u\in A.$ As $A$ is open, there exists $r>0$ such that $A\supset B(u,r)=\{v\in \mathbb R^n: \|v-u\|<r\}.$

For any vector $v\ne 0$ let $$R(v)=\sup \{x\geq 0 :   \{u+yv: y\in [0,x)\} \subset A    \}.$$ Note that  $R(v)\geq r/\|v\|>0$.

(i).  If $ R(v)=\infty$ for all $v \ne 0$ then  $A\supset \{u+yv: y\geq 0\land v\ne 0\}=\mathbb R^n.$

(ii). If  $R(v)<\infty$ for some $v\ne 0,$ note that $R(v)>0$ and $\{u+yv:y\in [0,R(v))\;\}\subset A,$ so  for every $\epsilon \in (0, R(v))$ we have $u+(R(v)-\epsilon)v\in A.$ As $A$ is closed, this implies $u+R(v)v\in A.$

But, as $A$ is open and $u+R(v)v\in A,$ there exists $s>0$ such that  $B(u+R(v)v,s)\subset A$ . This implies $$\{u+yv: y\in [0, R(v)+s)\}= \{u+yv;y\in [0,R(v)\}\cup \{u+yv: y\in [R(v),R(v)+s)\}\subset A$$ which contradicts the def'n of $R(v).$

Therefore $A$ cannot be a non-empty proper subset of $\mathbb R^n.$

Remark: Consider how this works in the simplest case $n=1$.